# Adding AJAX error: & success: breaks script

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an AJAX call that works fine with the following code:

```
            $.ajax({
               url: "filename.php",
               type:"POST",
               data: {
                   "pType":pType},
               dataType: "json", 
               complete:function(){
               $('body, html').animate({scrollTop:$('#adminFunctions').offset().top}, 'slow');
                    }
               });// end ajax call
```

However when I try to add error: & success parameters to the AJAX call, the script no longer functions.

```
$.ajax({
url: "filename.php",
type:"POST",
data: {
      "pType":pType},
dataType: "json", 

success: function() {
    $('#resultDiv').html('Success!' + response.responseText);
    $('body, html').animate({scrollTop:$('#logoText').offset().top}, 'slow');
    $('#addRentalPropertyForm').slideUp();
    $('#resultDiv').slideDown();
    $('#adminFunctionsA').slideDown();
    },

error: function() {
    $('#resultDiv').html('A problem has occurred.' + response.responseText);
    $('body, html').animate({scrollTop:$('#logoText').offset().top}, 'slow');
    $('#resultDiv').slideDown();
    },

});// end ajax call
```

Can anyone help guide me?  I cant seem to figure out why this is failing.  The complete: tag works fine and the data is submitted successfully, but when I added the error and success codes it does nothing.  Any help would be greatly appreciated, Im sure its something basic I am missing.

Comment: This seems to work however it looks to me like its only always catching the error and never success. I do get responses back when something is incorrect:      dataType: "json",
complete:function(){
$('body, html').animate({scrollTop:$('#logoText').offset().top}, 'slow');
  }
})// end ajax call
.success (function(response) { $('#resultDiv').html('Success:' + response.responseText); })
.error   (function(response)  { $('#resultDiv').html('Status:' + response.responseText); 
$('#resultDiv').slideDown();
;// This error code looks to be out of the ajax call and in the onclick event I guess.

Comment: try removing the extra comma after the error handler `},` <--

Answer (score 3):

```
 $.ajax({
  url: "filename.php",
  type:"POST",
  data: {
          "pType":pType},
  dataType: "json", 
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  success:function(data) {
                    // This outputs the result of the ajax request
                        console.log(data);
                        alert ('Appears successful');
                        // $('#resultDiv').html('Success!' + response.responseText);
                        $('body, html').animate({scrollTop:$('#logoText').offset().top}, 'slow');
                        $('#addRentalPropertyForm').slideUp();
                        $('#resultDiv').slideDown();
                        $('#adminFunctionsA').slideDown();
                    },
                    error: function(errorThrown){
                        console.log(errorThrown);
                        alert ('Seems to be a problem');
                        // $('#resultDiv').html('A problem has occurred.' + response.responseText);
                        $('body, html').animate({scrollTop:$('#logoText').offset().top}, 'slow');
                        $('#resultDiv').slideDown();
                        return false;
                    }  
    });
```

Comment: Why would this make a difference? Aren't parameters optional in JavaScript, and if you don't explicitly pass them in, then aren't the values undefined implicitly passed?

Comment: @Treker how should JavaScript understand that `response` is not a global variable but is the first parameter, if you don't write `function(response)`?

Comment: I removed the comma and still same problems.  However in looking at what 3558931 referenced I have changed the code to log to console.log.  I posted the new code above as an edit.

Answer (score 1):

1. You're not passing `response` to the `error` and `success` callbacks:
2. Since your `dataType` is `json` `response` will not have `responseText` property
3. Consider simplifying your callbacks to just `console.log( response )`; once you know the structure of `response` you can write whatever logic you need.

   `success: function(response) {
       $('#resultDiv').html('Success!' + response.responseText);`//????

   `error: function(response) {
       $('#resultDiv').html('A problem has occurred.' + response.responseText);`//???

**UPDATE**

1. You should not use `dataType:'json'` unless you're sure that `json` is being returned by `filename.php`. Otherwise you'll get a **`parseerror`**. Most likely that's what you're getting ... **the data returned cannot be parsed into a json object, therefore the error callback will fire.** **Use `dataType:'text'` or `dataType:'html'` and your success handler should fire.**

The following is not valid `JSON`:

```
<!-- DATA FROM ADD RENTAL HERE --> ↵↵
<script type="text/javascript">alert('Property ID: 34');
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">alert('Amenities ID: 34');</script>↵↵              ↵             <!-- END DATA FROM ADD RENTAL -->↵             ↵             ↵             ↵             <!-- START DATA FOR IMAGE UPLOAD -->↵             ↵             
<!-- END DATA FOR IMAGE UPLOAD -->↵                    ↵                
</div>↵
```

Comment: This did the trick! .. Thank you.  Guess I need to research a little more on how to encode this data.  I took out all the references to alerting from the receiving page, and trimmed down any spaces or unnec. text. but with the dataType as JSON it still failed.  Changed it to text and it works perfectly.  Ill do some reading up on dataType to see if I can track down why its not encoding it.

Comment: Thank you so much for everyones help!

Comment: Great! Feel free to select this answer if you feel it gave most value.